# Windows Server 2008 DHCPv6 Role only providing IPv6 address to Windows DHCPv6 clients?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, ipv6, dhcp-server

Testing a Windows Server 2008 Enterprise SP2 server with a DHCPv6 server role configured.

The Scope for the IPv6 range is 2001:db8:0:1::,  there is only one exclusion and that is 2001:db8:0:1::1 and that is the static IPv6 address for the server.

This is just  7 computers including the server attached on a single switch, with no other DHCP servers running, and no other connections.

2 Macs Running OS X 10.7.4

1 Windows 8 Release Preview system

1 Windows 7

1 Windows XP SP3 system

1 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system

Of those attached systems only the Windows 7, and 8 are able to obtain an IPv6 address from the DHCPv6 Server?  Windows XP does not work, but I a betting that may be due to the fact of an experimental IPv6 stack as noted in windows xp built in help.

However, both the Macs and Linux machines are setup to Auto-configure IPv6 address, yet they  fail to receive a lease from the Windows DHCPv6 server. Any idea what might be causing the other non-windows computers to not receive an IPv6 address from the Windows 2008 Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows XP does not have a DHCPv6 client, you can install Dibbler to resolve that.

Linux requires a DHCPv6 client daemon - Ubuntu should have this pre-installed but it may need to be enabled in network config, ditto for Mac OS.

Also, per RFC spec, a Router Advertisement with the stateful config flag set must first be sent before DHCPv6 address configuration is attempted - I'm sure you're already doing this but it's worth noting nonetheless.

Comment: RFC also specifies that if no RA-emmiting router is present on link, the host MUST attempt stateful configuration.

Comment: Good call I added a routing role to Win Server 2008, that may have been needed. Eitherway later I checked with Wireshark, there is a Router Advertisement getting sent out over the wire. needed to change settings in unbuntu for ipv6 from Automatic to "Automatic DHCP only"

Comment: Confirmed don't need a Routing Role for just DHCPv6 to work

Comment: Looks like OS X Lion 10.7 does not have a DHCPv6 client built in, looks like it can only auto config link local...